# Python - OpenCV - VideoCapture: getting incorrect frame timestamps in milliseconds on windows

Tags: windows, opencv

I am trying to get the milliseconds of each video frame in OpenCV and expecting same behavior on windows like on linux:

On Linux/IPython:

```
In [4]: ret,frame = v.read(); v.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
Out[4]: 41.522491349480966

In [5]: ret,frame = v.read(); v.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
Out[5]: 83.04498269896193

In [6]: ret,frame = v.read(); v.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
Out[6]: 124.5674740484429

In [16]: cv2.__version__
Out[16]: '2.4.8'
```

On Win7/IPython:

```
In [5]: ret,frame = v.read(); v.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
Out[5]: 1.0

In [6]: ret,frame = v.read(); v.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
Out[6]: 2.0

In [7]: ret,frame = v.read(); v.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
Out[7]: 3.0

In [14]: cv2.__version__
Out[14]: '2.4.13'
```

*Note that Windows gets a Anaconda environment with OpenCV 2.4.13 (cv2.pyd) copied to conda/site-packages*

I guess the only difference in the environment, then is, encoder and/or its library. I have seen that encoder (WMV2) is correctly showed in VLC when I play it in Windows and Ubuntu Linux both.

Any pointers to debug OpenCV (C++) ffmpeg dll calls is appreciated ?

**Edit:** For now have contended with this workaround using ffmpeg which IMO is a better solution
[How to fetch both live video frame and timestamp from ffmpeg to python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230269/how-to-fetch-both-live-video-frame-and-timestamp-from-ffmpeg-to-python-on-window/42442914#42442914)

Comment: I haven't yet found out the solution to this, I have figured out a workaround (using ffmpeg to get frame timestamps) as anyway my usecase requires timestamps from live camera as well which OpenCV won't provide. Will have to check with OpenCV forum by submitting them similar C++ code.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can use ffmpeg as an intermediate to stream video frame and timestamp, you could also refer my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230269/how-to-fetch-both-live-video-frame-and-timestamp-from-ffmpeg-to-python-on-window/42442914#42442914